# Jquery jstorage issue on IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstorage

i am using jquery jstorage in my jsp

importing statement

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<s:url value="/script/jstorage.min.js"/>'></script>
```

here is i am setting the value in jstorage
        var customerId = $.jStorage.get("customerId", true);//line

```
i can see below errors in my console

SCRIPT5022: jQuery, MooTools or Prototype needs to be loaded before jStorage! 
     jstorage.min.js?ver=4.5.8, line 2 character 315
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'get': object is null or undefined
```

**somehow  $.jStorage is null in IE  at line1 but not firefox/chrome(so works on firefox/chrome).**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Folks got the fix.Need to import jquery.json-2.3.min.js to make it work on IE